# Hiding the s3 url from the user, and enforcing authentication to view images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 requirements for an application:

1. Images can only be visible for authenticated users (JWT token)
2. The S3 location of the image cannot be visible to the end user (React application).

The current implementation sends a request to a service, and this service validates the user is authenticated, and then it uses the aws-sdk to connect to s3 and it streams the file back to the user.

This is a very processor intensive flow b/c each image has to be streamed from my server to the clients browser.

Is there a more efficient way to somehow use amazon's S3 infrastructure to send the files content to the browser, but at the same time satisfy my above requirements?

Comment: Have you looked at CloudFront?

Comment: @Marcin cloudfront doesn't have authentication does it?

Comment: Cloudfront can have a source path with  required authentication (signed url or cookie)

Answer (score -1):

> Images can only be visible for authenticated users (JWT token)

Common practice is using API Gateway + Lambda to validate the request JWT token and generate the signed url for the S3 object. Using Cognito it is possible to get the user's aws role credentials and generate the signed (temporary) url from the client side directly.

> The S3 location of the image cannot be visible to the end user

If under S3 location you mean the bucket name, it is always possible to use custom url for the S3 endpoint or using  Cloudfront with your own url.

One cannot completely hide where the client connects (mainly when running on web client).